# VS Code jsconfig advance alias glob paths

Tags: visual-studio-code, glob

I am trying to configure my VS Code React project and for doing so I have created a jsconfig with the following structure:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2019",
      "jsx": "react",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@Reducers/*": ["./src/reducers/*"],
        "@Selectors/*": ["./src/selectors/*"],
        "@Components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
        "@App/*": ["./src/components/App/*"],
        "@Loader/*": ["./src/components/Loader/*"]
    }
  },
  "include" : ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "config", ".vscode"]
}
```

The problem is that this only works if I import something like

```
import Blabla from "@Loader/blabla"
```

If I do the below, peek definition and things like that does not work:

```
import BlablaDefault from "@Loader"
```

To have this working I have to add an extra line in my paths definitions, so I have to have:

```
"@Loader": ["./src/components/Loader"]
"@Loader/*": ["./src/components/Loader/*"]
```

**Is there a way to get this in one line instead of two**? Also, I imagine that if I have more nested components I would need to do something similar...

Kind of:

```
import Deep from "@DeepStuff/blabla1/blabla2/blabla3"
```

**How would the glob expression be in this case?**

Thank you in advance and regards.